# shutdownReason : ConfigurationChange, but only static files changed?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5

I'm on IIS 7.5 and ASP.NET 4 with latest official updates. I'm logging all application shutdown reasons. All is working ok, but since a week strange shutdown reasons are logged.

This now happens when static files are updated on the server.
Example log:

shutDownMessage:

> ```
> Change Notification for critical directories.  bin dir change or directory rename
> HostingEnvironment initiated shutdown 
> HostingEnvironment caused shutdown  
> Change Notification for critical directories.  bin dir change or directory rename  
> Change Notification for critical directories.  bin dir change or directory rename
> ... (50 lines !) 
> Change in X:\IISTemp\ASPNET4Compilation\root\c6474edd\e8b7124f\hash\hash.web
> Change Notification for critical directories.  bin dir change or directory rename  
> Change Notification for critical directories.  bin dir change or directory rename  
> ... (20x !) 
> CONFIG change  
> CONFIG change  
> CONFIG change
> ```
>
> shutdownReason:   BinDirChangeOrDirectoryRename
>
> shutDownStack:
>
> ```
> at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)  
> at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()  
> at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.InitiateShutdownInternal()
> at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ShutdownAppDomain(String stackTrace)  
> at System.Web.HttpRuntime.OnCriticalDirectoryChange(Object sender, FileChangeEvent e)  
> at System.Web.FileChangesMonitor.OnCriticaldirChange(Object sender, FileChangeEvent e)  
> at System.Web.DirectoryMonitor.FireNotifications()
> at System.Web.Util.WorkItem.CallCallbackWithAssert(WorkItemCallback callback)  
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)  
> at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
> at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()  
> at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
> ```

Any idea ?

Comment: Where are the static files located? How are they updated? If they're in the same location as the application then this looks like expected behaviour.

Comment: ASP.NET app will restart if there is any change in bin directory. Make sure that you are not copying the static files into that directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been fixed by updating time sync settings.

Comment: What time sync settings? The servers syncing with time.windows.com?

Comment: I'm just curious if that's what you meant. Or if you were talking about another time sync settings, such as a scheduled task's 'Synchronize across timezones'

Comment: Because I'm having a very similar problem, but the server (Windows server 2008) doesn't have the 'Internet Time' tab when I go to adjust the server time. Sorry, couldn't edit the last post.

Comment: Well, drifting is well known if you windows server runs virtualized. The Windows NTP service is not sufficient, you should add a scheduled task to force sync. And use a non overloaded ntp server (your own).

Comment: Hi Softlion, would you mind elaborating on your response? What do you mean by "updating time sync settings"? Thanks much!